# Upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu Pro

Tags: 16.04

Is it possible to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running on an AWS vm to Ubuntu Pro to gain access to the extended support? Or do I need to spin up a new instance?

Answer (score 4):

### Ubuntu 16.04 ESM

I tried out ESM on Ubuntu 14.04, (16.04 should be the same).
It was pretty easy to set up.

I started out by installing an Ubuntu 14.04.4 ISO I had in my downloads folder. (I probably should have downloaded ubuntu-14.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso from https://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/) . At this point we at least know for a fact that the downloading of 14.04 and 16.04 Desktop and Server is fully supported by Canonical.

During the install process I selected the option to `download updates while installing`. I think that if I would have used point release 6, there might have been fewer updates and the process might have gone faster.

It was a pleasure to log into 14.04 after so long, sort of nostalgic.

First priority was security. For 14.04 and 16.04, this means signing up for Ubuntu Advantage (UA) client and installing ESM.

The Ubuntu discourse page for information on installing Ubuntu ESM is https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-advantage-client/21788. the page directed me to https://ubuntu.com/advantage where I completed the registration process and ended up with a **free token**.

Back on https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-advantage-client/21788 I continued with **Installing the UA client** by running a couple of commands as instructed. Next I proceeded to **Attach the UA client**. I ran the line I got when registering `sudo ua attach [UNIQUECODE]`, (Please use your own free token).

Running `sudo ua status` I confirmed that ESM was enabled.

I completed the upgrade by running `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`. The installer ran for quite a while.

I ran Software Updater and It installed quite a few security updates.
All Settings/Overview tells me **System Up-To-Date**.

It appears to me that  Canonical is truly supporting Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 for free. The question is whether Ask Ubuntu will also continue to support Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 until their End of Life as claimed on the Help page?

**AND EVERYTHING WAS FREE**

Comment: 1 small issue: AWS is a little bit different than a normal install.

Comment: @Rinzwind I do not recall a need to reboot while setting up ESM. Updating process seems to me to be the same as before ESM. Is this not true with instances? I would agree that a backup is recommended before proceeding. I better study AWS a little more.

Comment: Yes and no. You can upgrade but it is far too risky. Since Canonical provides instances for this it is far easier to connect a copy of your personal partition to a copy of instance. And after that you can burn your old instance if wanted.

Comment: @Rinzwind So what provision is there for continuing to receive security for 14.04 and 16.04 with AWS **without cost**? Some poor people have a valid reason not to upgrade to 18.04 and higher. Are these Canonical instances free?

Comment: Same rules apply... you create a new instance of your old instance and you alter the new instance. You do not mess with your current instance. And only when the new instance is working as intended you can burn the old one (or keep it as a backup)

Comment: @Rinzwind, Thanks great info, sounds like I got some new stuff to keep me busy.

Comment: As OP says, Ubuntu Pro is the best choice for new 16.04 instances as this includes  Extended Security Maintenance (ESM) for 16.04 (among other benefits). For existing 16.04 VMs that you do not want to reinstall, you need to attach ESM another way, such as set out in this answer. See:
https://ubuntu.com/16-04
"ESM is available for free on up to three machines and for broader enterprise use through an Ubuntu Advantage subscription."

There's more info for Azure here:
https://ubuntu.com/16-04/azure

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running on an AWS vm to Ubuntu Pro to gain access to the extended support?

Never ever for whatever reason do you upgrade an instance.

> Or do I need to spin up a new instance?

Always create a new instance.

And for the simplest of reasons: you do not have a live session, nor do you have access to GRUB. If the boot fails due to some stupid error your instance is dead, gone, never to return and you will need to depend on backups to restore your system. You only take that risk when you are toying around with instances.

Besides that:

> 4th December 2019 – Canonical today announced the availability of Ubuntu Pro images for Amazon Web Services (AWS). Available via AWS Marketplace, covering Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS, these new premium images allow enterprises to purchase extended maintenance, broader security coverage, and critical compliance features by simply selecting and running an image on Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) — with no contract required.

Ubuntu Pro IS an image. Not an upgrade from another version.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to change anything if you want ESM. After April 22 simply sign up for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is now possible:
https://ubuntu.com/blog/upgrade-your-existing-ubuntu-lts-instances-to-ubuntu-pro-in-aws

> In April 2023, Amazon Web Services (AWS) released a new functionality that allows users running Ubuntu LTS to upgrade their instances to Ubuntu Pro with just a few clicks. [...]

Supports:

> Ubuntu LTS EC2 machines from 16.04 onwards

Summarising the steps, you need to:

1. Shut down the instance(s)
2. Go to the AWS License Manager and select License type conversion on the left side menu.
3. Click the Create license type conversion button.
4. Select Ubuntu LTS from the dropdown menu and choose the instances you want to upgrade.
5. Click Next and select Ubuntu Pro as the License type destination.
6. Review the information and click Convert. (May take some time, monitor progress on the License Manager dashboard.)
7. Verify that the instance has been upgraded to Ubuntu Pro by running `pro status`

Amazon also describes this here:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/04/aws-license-manager-ec2-instances-ubuntu-pro-operating-system/

> [AWS License Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/license-manager/) announces a new feature to upgrade EC2 instances with Ubuntu LTS (Long Term Support) operating system to Ubuntu Pro. With Ubuntu Pro subscription, customers get five years of Expanded Security Maintenance (ESM) on the Ubuntu LTS releases from Canonical. Using this License Manager feature, customers can upgrade their Ubuntu LTS instances in-place to Ubuntu Pro without needing to migrate to a new Ubuntu Pro Amazon Machine Image (AMI). For the use of upgraded EC2 instances with Ubuntu Pro, you will be charged on a per-second basis at the applicable [On-Demand](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) or [Savings Plan](https://aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/compute-pricing/) rates for Ubuntu Pro. [...]

> This feature is available in all AWS Regions where AWS License Manager is available, except the AWS GovCloud(US) and China Regions. To get started, visit [AWS License Manager console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/license-manager/), choose License type conversion from the left pane and select ‘Create license type conversion’. You can select ‘Ubuntu’ as the Source Operating System and follow the steps mentioned in the [AWS License Manager user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/license-manager/latest/userguide/license-conversion.html) to upgrade to Ubuntu Pro.

Answer (score 0):

The official answer is: You can't do an in-place upgrade from Ubuntu LTS to Ubuntu Pro, since they are different products in AWS.

Nevertheless, there are two ways for doing this:

1. Is to re-deploy in a new Pro instance
2. To get a Ubuntu Advantage Token to get ESM (Extended Security Maintenance). You can get one for free if is for personal use. https://ubuntu.com/advantage

Comment: This is no longer the case. AWS released a way to upgrade running instances to Pro using License Manager