# When will Ubuntu Advantage Essential for Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop become freely available?

Tags: 16.04, esm

The [Ubuntu Advantage](https://ubuntu.com/advantage) pricing information says:

> "Anyone can use UA Infrastructure Essential for free on up to 3
> machines (limitations apply). (...) Initially, this free subscription
> is available for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS only."

I should like to get it for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, will it become free at the start of End-of-Life time? If not, when?

Comment: https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/ ESM for Ubuntu 16.04 begins 30 April 2021...   many links were offered relating to ESM including https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-esm-migration-path let alone the usual https://www.ubuntu.com/esm etc

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle does not show a gap between End of Standard maintenance and ESM. My experience activating ESM with 14,04 can be found at this link :https://askubuntu.com/a/1330857/43926

Comment: I have run into this same problem. I just followed the steps that they claim only work for 14.04. I am having trouble determining if it worked. I can run` ua status` and see that `esm-infra` and livepatch are enabled, but it seems that updates are not actually being found by `unattended-upgrades`

Comment: That's the same with me, but updates with the synaptic package manager do come in, I just got the latest one an hour ago :)