# ESM needed: more payment options for Ubuntu Advantage subscription, besides by credit card number?

Tags: 16.04, esm

The problem: for security reasons, as a general rule my bank (BNL-BNP Paribas) does no longer support payments made online by credit card. Nonetheless, I can still use my credit card for online orders with payment made through PayPal, since my PayPal account charges on my credit card. Unfortunately, payment via PayPal is not an option for Ubuntu Advantage (UA) subscription, which I need to get ESM for my Ubuntu 16.04 installation, approaching End Of Life. Another option that could solve the problem would be that of payment by direct charge on my bank account (e.g. this is the way I can issue orders to Amazon), but this option is not available for UA subscription  either. Is there some hope that more payment options will become available for UA subscription in the future?

Comment: This would likely be best asked of Canonical (https://ubuntu.com/security/esm in the contact us section) rather than asking users on a user support site.

Comment: Are you sure the free for a limited number of machines (3 for anyone, 50 depending upon...) will not meet your needs?

Comment: I installed ESM for 14.04. It was completely free for one machine, I think the free limit is three machines. Here is my experience: https://askubuntu.com/a/1330857/43926

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, the free for 3 machines would be more than enough for me. I thought it was not yet available for Ubuntu 16.04 (hence I tried the purchase) because installing the ua token failed, but now I understand (from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330842/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-lts-to-ubuntu-pro/1330857#1330857) by C.S. Cameron) that I need to install a UA client first. I did so and now the problem is SOLVED. Thanks for these answers, are quite helpful!

Comment: Good, you can accept your own answer after a few days (?) and it gets marked solved, and you get some points.

Comment: Thank you ubfan1, I'll do so next week. My current knowledge about earning points is very limited :)

Answer (score 0):

Another purchase mechanism is through AWS Marketplaces. You can search for Ubuntu Advantage, pay there and you will get access to ubuntu.com/advantage for getting the token.